# React Native Flatlist if return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Below is my flatlist renderrow function, does not provide this condition    `this.state.date.format('YYYYMMDD') <= moment(item.tarih).format('YYYYMMDD') && this.state.secilenAyBasi.year() == moment(item.tarih).format('YYYY') ?` and renderRow function return null for all items(so if doesn't return element) return just want component how I do that,I tried ListEmptyComponent props but I didn't want the result thanks

```
  renderRow = (item,index) => {
    return (
    this.state.date.format('YYYYMMDD') <= moment(item.tarih).format('YYYYMMDD') && this.state.secilenAyBasi.year() == moment(item.tarih).format('YYYY') ?
    <View>
     {!this.aynıTarihmi(item,index) ?
    <View style={styles.etkinlikTarihContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.etkinlikTarihText}>
        {moment(item.tarih).format('DD MMMM YYYY')}
      </Text>
    </View> : null}
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.etkinlikView,this.aynıTarihmi(item,index) ? {borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 1 }: null]}>
    <View style={{alignItems: 'center', minWidth:70}}>
        {item.mod_txt != "Tüm Gün" ? 
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:'center'}}> 
            {this.getTime(item.baslangic)}
            {this.getTime(parseInt(item.baslangic, 10) +parseInt(item.sure, 10))}
          </View> :
          item.mod_txt == "Tüm Gün" ?
          <Text style={{color:'black'}}> Tüm Gün </Text> : null}
      </View>
      <View
        style={[styles.etkinlikBordorView,{borderRightColor: item.renk ? item.renk : 'green'}]}
      />
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 15, marginLeft: 5,color:'black',marginVertical:5}}>
          {item.metin ? item.metin : 'Etkinlik Yok'}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View> : null
    )}
```

this my flatlist component:

```
  getActivity() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.etkinlikContainer}>
      <FlatList
      data={this.state.takvimgirdileriStt}
      extraData={this.state.date}
      renderItem={({item,index}) =>this.renderRow(item, index)}
      keyExtractor = {(item,index) => index.toString()}
      />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your condition is wrong.

if date formats are the same , can you try the following code

(moment(this.state.date.format('YYYYMMDD')).diff(moment(item.tarih).format('YYYYMMDD'))) <0 && moment(this.state.secilenAyBasi.year()).isSame(moment(item.tarih).format('YYYY'))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll want a nulled row. You should filter you list `this.state.takvimgirdileriStt` before sending it to the FlatList. You can use something like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter)'s `_.filter` method for this. I'm not sure when your data gets set, but you'll want to do something like this after you have the data.

```
var data = this.state.takvimgirdileriStt;
_.filter(data, function (item) {
    return this.state.date.format('YYYYMMDD') <= moment(item.tarih).format('YYYYMMDD') && this.state.secilenAyBasi.year() == moment(item.tarih).format('YYYY');
}, this);
this.setState({ takvimgirdileriStt: data });
```

However, I'm pretty sure you can also return an empty `<View></View>`

So instead of doing the check before the opening View, try it inside:

```
renderRow = (item, index) => {
    var check = this.state.date.format('YYYYMMDD') <= moment(item.tarih).format('YYYYMMDD') && this.state.secilenAyBasi.year() == moment(item.tarih).format('YYYY');
    return (
        <View>
            {check && (
                // ... all your stuff
            )}
        </View>
}
```

I also pulled out the check because it's a little easier to read.

Comment: No I dont want nulled row,I want if flatlist return null (return none component) render just one my custom component if return not null all item not render my custom component